# Why does LoadLibrary fail whilst LoadLibraryA succeeds in loading a DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, loadlibrary

I'm trying to load a DLL into C++ but was getting error code 126, which I think means the DLL couldn't be found. After some poking around I changed `LoadLibrary` to `LoadLibraryA` and suddendly it worked. However, I am at a complete loss as to why. I realise that I haven't provided the dll for this code to be runable but would be greatful if somebody could provide an explaination as to why this is happening? And prehaps an example of how to get `LoadLibary` working.

## Broken version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef char* (*gf_getCurrentLibraryVersion) ();

int main() {

    gf_getCurrentLibraryVersion getVersion;

    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)"libsbnw.dll");
    if (hLib) {
        getVersion = (gf_getCurrentLibraryVersion)GetProcAddress(hLib, "gf_getCurrentLibraryVersion");
        printf("Version = %s\n", getVersion());
    }
    else {
        printf("Error loading dll: %d/n", GetLastError());
    }
    printf("Hit any key to continue\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and outputs

```
Error loading dll: 126/nHit any key to continue
```

to console

## Working version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef char* (*gf_getCurrentLibraryVersion) ();

int main() {

    gf_getCurrentLibraryVersion getVersion;

    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibraryA("libsbnw.dll");
    if (hLib) {
        getVersion = (gf_getCurrentLibraryVersion)GetProcAddress(hLib, "gf_getCurrentLibraryVersion");
        printf("Version = %s\n", getVersion());
    }
    else {
        printf("Error loading dll: %d/n", GetLastError());
    }
    printf("Hit any key to continue\n");
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles and outputs

```
version is: 1.3.4
```

Comment: What compiler and flags are you using?  Are you defining `_UNICODE` etc.?

Comment: This is what happens when you lie to the compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your `LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)"libsbnw.dll")` call is that your build environment converts that to a `LoadLibraryW` call, but the way you are trying to pass a wide-character string is wrong.

As you have it, you are simply casting a `const char*` pointer to a `const wchar_t*` pointer, which won't work (for example, it will interpret the initial `"li"` characters as a *single* 16-bit character).

What you need to do is specify the string literal as a **wide character** constant, using the `L` prefix:

```cpp
 HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(L"libsbnw.dll");
```

Or, alternatively, using the `TEXT()` macro (which will boil down to the same, when using the `UNICODE` build environment):

```cpp
 HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("libsbnw.dll"));
```

Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Ordinarily the compiler will try to point out when you're making a mistake.  But in this case you've told it not to by adding an explicit cast to the string.

```
HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)"libsbnw.dll");
                           //^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm assuming you've built your app with Unicode enabled, which defines a macro converting `LoadLibrary` to `LoadLibraryW`.  The parameter must be a *wide-character* string.

```
HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibraryW(L"libsbnw.dll");
```

There's another macro you can use when you're not sure if the app will be compiled with Unicode or not, `TEXT()` or the shorter form `_T()`.  Not recommended for modern code since needing to turn Unicode on or off hasn't been a problem in many years, just use Unicode always.

```
HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("libsbnw.dll"));
```

Comment: Note that the best practice for modern Windows programming is to follow the [UTF-8 Everywhere Manifest](https://utf8everywhere.org/) and just explicitly call the Unicode version of Win32 APIs: ``LoadLibraryW(L"libsbnw.dll");``

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn that's an interesting viewpoint but hardly "best practice". If you don't use `wchar_t` you're working against the Windows API and creating a lot of unnecessary friction.

Comment: That's neither an interesting viewpoint nor related to the *"UTF-8 Everywhere"* movement. That's just *"best practice"*. The practice here being to be explicit. Don't rely on the generic-text macros to clean up after you. Just call the *function* with matching parameter types. If you're using `wchar_t`, call the Unicode variant of the API. It's been two decades now, and we're still having trouble driving that point home?

Comment: @IInspectable did you miss that the first part of my answer was to make the call with an explicit wide-character string?  The text macro part was just to be complete, since you're likely to run into it in existing code.  UTF-8 Everywhere is the exact opposite, constantly switching between char and wchar_t strings depending on context.

Comment: There are two parts to generic-text mappings: Transformation of the function names and transformation of the arguments. You are only explicit on the latter, not the former. That's a bug, just waiting to happen.

Comment: @IInspectable as long as you don't circumvent type checking with an explicit C-style cast, the compiler will catch that error and prevent it from being a bug.  That's an important point to make in the context of this specific question.

Comment: It's a bug, no matter what. Whether you discover it at compile time or run time depends on the tool you use to compile the code. This question initially had a C++ and C tag. One of those compilers will not issue a diagnostic. The really important point is that you are being inconsistent. The severity of the consequences of this inconsistency is not something you control.

Comment: @IInspectable it's been a long time since I've used pure C.  Will it really not complain when passing a `char*` pointer to a function that takes a `wchar_t*`? And the source of the inconsistency is the crazy way that Microsoft decided to handle the transition to Unicode - they shouldn't have tried to paper over the difference between the `A` and `W` versions of the API with macros.

Comment: My key point was: Don't rely on the macros and explicitly use the ``W`` version with a ``wchar_t`` string (i.e. ``L"libsbnw.dll"``). This is the "best practice" even if you adopt UTF-8 everywhere because Windows APIs have been Unicode 16 LE for ages. Recent versions of Windows 10 are trying to enable true UTF-8 with the ``A`` version but even that's a user setting for codepage. Also, don't use ``TCHAR`` and ``TEXT(`` macros which date back to the transition from Windows 3.1

Comment: @mar: A C compiler may [issue a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/Ect8mY) at best. It's perfectly valid C code to pass `"it's just high-level assembly"` to a function expecting an `unsigned short*`. I don't know how else Microsoft should have handled the transition to UCS-2. If you do, let us know. In picking a strategy, don't forget that all you have is late 80's compilers and languages (work on Windows NT started in 1988).

Comment: `_T` is not the *"shorter form"* of `TEXT`. The latter controls the character set used by the SDK, whereas the former controls the character set used by the CRT. Those are different things. [TEXT vs. _TEXT vs. _T, and UNICODE vs. _UNICODE](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643) contrasts their use.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the link.  But if you read the last line, he admits he doesn't even know why there's both `TEXT` and `_T` except to save some typing.

Comment: If you read the last line *carefully*, it doesn't say that at all. He simply doesn't know, why there's a need for the `_T` macro. He fully understands the significance of the leading underscore and surely wouldn't suggest that a macro with a leading underscore could be used interchangeably with one that doesn't have a leading underscore.